# Halakhot of raising babies

Tags: halacha, children-parenting, baby-infant

I don't think I've ever encountered halakhot that pertain to interacting with newborns, but as any new parent knows, such interactions take up a great deal of one's time, during the day, at night, over the week and on Shabbat.

Are there halakhot that concern how to raise one's children from so young an age? How should one dress them, clean them and change them? When and where is it especially propitious to interact with them, what things might it be good to show them or to let them hear, when might it be advisable to *not* interact with them, and what sorts of things *shouldn't* they see or hear?

If there are halakhot of this nature, what are they and where are they recorded? And if this is something that halakhic sources don't touch on, why not? They seem to deal with just about everything else, and this strikes me as a fairly large subject.

Answer (score 4):

R Simcha Bunim Cohen wrote a book called [Children in Halacha](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9780899066110.html) (amazon reviews [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0899066119)) which (according to artscroll description)

> takes the mystery out of the halachic responsibilities involved in
>   raising children. It is clear, easy-to-use, and documented. All
>   pertinent halachic details regarding children and Kashrus, Tznius,
>   Yomim Tovim, Berachos, Shabbos, and more are included.

He covers many of the questions you mention and more (e.g., chinuch, prayer/brachot near children, yichud, food, bathing, cleaning, clothing, nursing, carrying a child, toys). I didn't find that he adresses what children should see/hear.

There is another older and good book from R Hayim Donin ([To Raise A Jewish Child: A Guide For Parents](http://amzn.com/0465086357)) which as I recall is more focused on education.

The online material I found is much more focused on specific issues, e.g.,

- [Baby and toddler care on Shabbat](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/77897/jewish/Baby-and-Toddler-Care-on-Shabbat.htm)
- [Warming a baby bottle](https://www.dailyhalacha.com/Display.asp?ClipID=3007)
- [Baby monitors on Shabbat](http://halachayomit.co.il/en/Default.aspx?HalachaID=3254&PageIndex=23)
- [Baby wipes on Shabbat](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/Display.asp?PageIndex=24&ClipID=902)